# Prevent default and transfer text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

The goal is that once `loginAccount` is clicked, it takes the text from the id `input-1` and puts it in `username`. This should happen to `password` as well and then the form submits. But for some reason, `e.preventDefault()` is not doing it's thing and the form gets submitted anyway without copying the values first.

```
$("#loginAccount").submit(function(e) {
        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#username').val($('#input-1').val());
        $('#password1').val($('#input-2').val());
        $("#loginAccount").submit();
    });
```

Comment: This will probably be easier if you do it onclick rather than on the submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#loginAccount").click(function(e) {
    //prevent Default functionality
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#username').val($('#input-1').val());
    $('#password1').val($('#input-2').val());
    $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

Comment: That's great in that now the text is being transferred, but now the form won't submit lol.

Comment: what is the <form> id? trying $('#formid').submit();

Comment: Thank you very much! I was originally using the id of the button, not the whole form.